# Is JSON too redundant like xml?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, database, optimization

**Abstract:**

In json format we have key value pairs. For each object the same key is repeated. Isn't this a redundancy? Can this be changed to database-table format in which first row has all the keys, next rows represent objects having values.

**Detail:**

It is said that xml is more verbose and redundant because of it's ending tags. So the alternative is json. But I found json too redundant. The redundancies I found are:

1. Repeated keys in every object instance.
2. Unnecessary double quotes for every key and value's name.

For 2 I found an explanation that since javascript didn't allow reserved keywords like `function`, `if`, `else` as keys and Mr. Crockford wanted to keep json simple he chose to use quotes.

**Question1:** Instead of using quotes in json data why don't we make the json parser to add quotes when data is reached to client? E.g. server should send data as:

```
[
    {
        product: car,
        price: 100
    }, 

    {
        product: bus,
        price: 1000
    }
]
```

And the json parser should convert this on client side to:

```
[
    {
        "product": "car",
        "price": "100"
    }, 

    {
        "product": "bus",
        "price": "1000"
    }
]
```

Now let's talk about the point one. Suppose we have the following data in json:

```
[
    {
        "product": "car",
        "price": "100"
    }, 

    {
        "product": "bus",
        "price": "1000"
    },
    {
        "product": "Train",
        "price": "100000"
    }
]
```

Here the key `product` has been repeated three times and key `price` is also repeated three times. In table database format this data would be as:

```
+=========+===================+
| product |       price       |
+=========+===================+
|   car   |        100        |
+---------+-------------------+
|   bus   |        1000       |
+---------+-------------------+
|  train  |        100000     |
+---------+-------------------+
```

In table format we have `product` and `price` repeated none times. So this format must be the optimal format. To acheive this in json I thought up the following methods:

1. Table like arrays:

+=-------------------------  //For making below code formatted

```
[
    ["product", "price"],
    ["car", "100"],
    ["bus", "1000"],
    ["train", "100000"]

]
```

We are having a lot of arrays. There can be another improvement:

2. Individual Array of all keys and another individual array for all values:

+-=---------- //For making below code formatted

```
[
    ["product", "price"],
    ["car", "bus", "train"],
    ["100", "1000", "100000"]
]
```

Now there will be only three arrays. This is the most optimal approach which can be slightly improved to be more meaningful:

```
{
    "product": ["car", "bus", "train"],
    "price": ["100", "1000", "100000"]
}
```

Now we see that the redundancy in json can be removed.

**Question2:** Is it true that json is rendundant and the format can be improved further?

My thinking is that in some case data won't have same keys for each object so my methods won't fit onto them. So it is left to developer to reformat json as per the practical need arise. Another thinking is that may be my format when gzipped is just same in size as the original json gzipped file size.

**Question3:** If all the objects of a json data have same keys then is my format when gzipped smaller in size than original json gzipped file size?

Comment: Quotes in particular would be needed, otherwise you start running into whitespace control problems. E.g.: a description, if your product price example had a description, it would be multiple words, with no quotes, your parser could run into issues and ambiguity.

Comment: @ChrisWatts How would there be ambiguity if all description values are seperated with commas? Comma can act like a separator just like double quotes are.

Comment: Consider unstructured data. Then JSON format can prevent a lot of unnecessary 'whitespace' in your data. Anyone: feel free to elaborate/improve this as an answer, I don't have the time :-)

Comment: @user31782 consider the following: `"description" : "a meaningful description of the product, created by me", ...` and `description : a meaningful description of the product, created by me,` the second wouldnt parse, and therefore starts to restrict your supported character sets. Its the same for csv format, where quotes are used to encapsulate the data to prevent mistaken parsing.

Comment: @ChrisWatts `commas` could be escaped with slash, just like double quotes are in normal json format. I think this is `"` vs `,`. It may be argued that `commas` are more common in text than `quotes` -- so we should use comma. How about using something like `EOF` as a separator which would have minor chances to exist in text?

Comment: 1. doug spec'd quotes on keys to make the spec fit on one page and to allow IE to take keys like "continue" and "default" (and even "class"), 2. arrays are JSON, so choose your shape to suit your needs with regard to quick consumption and optimal bandwidth. 3. gzip blast xml and json repetition, so i would expect the before and after to be comparable, depending on uniqueness and amount of leftover "good symbols". aside: loose CSV is about the most compact format.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a lot of redundancy.

For example, "product" could be replaced by "1" and "price" by "2". Or indeed, why use 16 bits? If there are only two keys, they only need one bit.

But the whole tone of your message is that redundancy is bad. That's not a universally acknowledged truth. Redundancy has many benefits, which is why natural language has so much redundancy.

Comment: But if `product` is replaced by `1` and `price` by `2` then how would the client know `1` stands for product` and `2` for `price`? And what are the advantages of redundancy? What kind of redundancy is in natural languages? Please explain. I have very less knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks for poking a general button :) IMHO, redundancy is a two-edged sword. It is good if it is sparing and paired with a way to detect/correct errors. It is bad if it is both profligate and lacks such a mechanism, because its size simply invites errors that cannot be easily detected. i.e. 50% redundancy might be good, but 1000% is likely to be bad. Choosing the right amount of redundancy is a skill.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question1:** Instead of using quotes in json data why don't we make the json parser to add quotes when data is reached to client?

Quoted values are used to (a) identify the value's [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) as a string and (b) allow any characters (including commas and escaped quotes) to be used in a string value. In particular, the end quotation mark delimits the end of text - if it weren't present, the parser wouldn't be able to differentiate between something like the following (where each line represents a key/value pair):

```
key1: hello, world: hello, world,
key2: hello, universe: hello, universe
```

...or...

```
key1: hello,
world: hello, world,
key2: hello,
universe: hello, universe
```

As you've mentioned, commas in the text could be required to be escaped to attempt to get round this:

```
key1: hello\, world: hello\, world,
key2: hello\, universe: hello\, universe
```

But as you've also mentioned, commas are generally more common in text than quotation marks so this may well have the overall effect of *adding* size (e.g. consider a JSON value that is the complete works of Shakespeare) and would also go against existing conventions used in other languages.

**Other possible redundancy?**

One *theoretical* small piece of redundancy is the starting quotation mark for a JSON string value: If it weren't there a parser would still have all the information required to interpret keys and values. But removing them would look pretty odd:

```
"key1": a string value",
"key2": \"I really don't like this!\""
```

> **Question2:** Is it true that json is rendundant and the format can be improved further?

The answer to this depends on what is meant by "improved". JSON wasn't designed to use the minimal possible number of characters to represent the data: A balance is being struck between conciseness and human readability, and the latter is of considerable importance.

> **Question3:** If all the objects of a json data have same keys then is my format when gzipped smaller in size than original json gzipped file size?

You could easily test this out yourself if you do decide to go ahead with the proposed format.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel certain that your objects are always like

```
{
    "product": "car",
    "price": "100"
}
```

you can reduce "redundancy" by storing them as arrays like you did here:

```
[
    ["car", "100"],
    ["bus", "1000"],
    ["train", "100000"]
]
```

But most of the time you cannot be sure that your data is stored "correctly" because it's somehow generated. Therfore it's mostly an advantage to store your data in object notation (btw this is what's JSON is shorthand for). You simply **can check if your stored objects have certain attributes** in your code.

So **don't blame JSON that it offers redundancy, because you could bypass it**, if you'd like to.
It depends on you how you use JSON.

Comment: Yes I am sure my object are always like that. It is basically a set of images loaded with ajax.

Comment: So then you could use the array notation.